# Open all files containing certain text

Tags: command-line, search

I am looking for a terminal way. Open all files in `/foo/bar` containing the string `foobar`. How?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You didn't say how you want to open them :)

One way is to use grep to recursively look for the string in your files (-r). Use -l to ask grep to output only the filenames of matching files. This will output one filename per line, use xargs to build a suitable command line for your editor.

```
grep -r -l foobar /foo/bar/ | xargs vim
```

this also works with gedit; just change vim for gedit.

You can also use find for this but it's more complicated IMHO:

```
find /foo/bar -type -f -exec grep -l foobar {} \;  | xargs vim
```

Answer (score 1):

Opens files containing `foobar` one by one in `vim`:

```
for f in $(find /foo/bar -type f); do 
    if [ ! -z "$(grep foobar $f)" ]; then
        vim $f 
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

It also works with

```
evince *2010*
```

It will open all the files containing 2010 in their title, for the directory you are currently working on.